# Update a Column in custom sharepoint list using web services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to Update a few columns of a custom sharepoint list using web services. 
I am trying to achieve that using UpdateListItems() of Lists web service. I do get success code,  i.e. "0x00000000", but when I check the value in my list I find all of them updated but one. The flow goes like:

- Create the custom list by using AddList() of List web service.
- Update the List to set the four custom fields.
- Update the view.

Now, if I update the items on the list programmatically, 3 out 4 columns get updated but the fourth one doesn't. The wierd thing is I get the success code for the fourth column as well.
I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have compared my code from the msdn link, and its all the same. I am pretty sure there is no problem in the code. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently faced a similar issue. The problem was that I was trying to update a read-only field in the list. Please check to ensure that whatever list/list-fields you are updating are not marked as Read-Only. In case they are, update the list-fields to set ReadOnly as false before you fire the update. Hope this helps.